# removing irrelevant items from a List vs building up new List with relevant items

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am detecting figures in a bitmap pixel-by-pixel. Every figure is starting with a size of one pixel. The most figures are growing but some stay small.

I collect the figures sequentially in an `ArrayList`. In the next step I would like to reduce the list removing the small figures.

The first step collects about 1500 figures. The second step removes about 1/3 of them.

What performs better:

1. removing the items from the list
   Since removing items performs better using a `LinkedList`:

   - I could use a `LinkedList` already in the first step, but then building up this list performs worse than using the `ArrayList` (since it is more expensive to create an `LinkedList` item than adding an object to an `ArrayList`)
     therefore
   - I still use the `ArrayList` which every time has to copy the items after the removed item to the position of the removed item. To reduce the amount of items to be copied, I could start traverse the list from the last index.
2. building up a new list with only bigger figures

   - I create a new `ArrayList` initializing it with 3/4 size of original figures list and then add only the bigger figures to the new list.

I guess, working with such a few items, none of the options will result in a measurable performance gain. But what does perform better for a bigger amount of items?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from testing this yourself?

Comment: Is it really difficult to change your implementation when needed? I don't think so. Premature optimization is often leading to too difficult code...

Comment: Why dont you just pass a filter to the method you use to cellect  the figures and accept / add to the list only the figures that are big enough?

Comment: Is the order of your list important? If not you may not want a list at all but a set

Comment: @Jon Skeet: There is no reason, why I couldn't test it. Beyond this empiric approach I'm also interested in your considerations.

Comment: @A4L: Yes ... that's where I actually switched to. I am applying three filters on different stages. There first filter checks already the first pixel. So if this check fails, I can skip the whole processing of the figure.

Comment: @Richard Tingle: The order is not important. A set is semantically the more appropriate structure, since there are no two equal figures in the list. But which set performs better than an ArrayList for example?

Answer (score 2):

Using the following test program, I have found that

#### ArrayList

1000 object references, 25% to be removed from the arrayList;

- Removing from an existing arraylist; 0.565ms
- Recreating a new arrayList; 0.573ms

100000 object references, 25% to be removed from the arrayList;

- Removing from an existing arraylist; 1028ms
- Recreating a new arraylist; 8.66ms
- Recreating a new arraylist (presized); 2ms

On small scales it doesn't really matter, on large scales creating a new list is key, preferably presized

#### HashSet

1000 object references, 25% to be removed from the arrayList;

- Removing from an existing hashset; 0.602ms
- Recreating a new hashset; 2.64ms

100000 object references, 25% to be removed from the arrayList;

- Removing from an existing hashset; 28ms
- Recreating a new hashset; 37ms

On small scales removing from an existing set seems to be faster but both are comprable on scales that matter.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3d;

public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args){
            voidTestArrayList(100000);
            voidTestHashSet(100000);

            
        }
        

        
        public static void voidTestArrayList(int samples){
            {
                Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayList=new ArrayList<Vector3d>();
                 preamble(collectionArrayList,samples);
                 testRemoveQuarter(collectionArrayList);
            }
            {
                Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayList2=new ArrayList<Vector3d>();
                Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayListDestination=new ArrayList<Vector3d>();
                preamble(collectionArrayList2,samples);

                testRetain3Quarter(collectionArrayList2,collectionArrayListDestination);
            }
            {
                Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayList3=new ArrayList<Vector3d>();
                preamble(collectionArrayList3,samples);
                Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayListDestination3=new ArrayList<Vector3d>(collectionArrayList3.size());
                testRetain3QuarterPresized(collectionArrayList3,collectionArrayListDestination3);
            }
        }
        
        public static void voidTestHashSet(int samples){
             Collection<Vector3d> collectionHashSet=new HashSet<Vector3d>();
             preamble(collectionHashSet,samples);
             testRemoveQuarter(collectionHashSet);
             
             Collection<Vector3d> collectionHashSet2=new HashSet<Vector3d>();
             Collection<Vector3d> collectionHashSetDestination=new HashSet<Vector3d>();
             preamble(collectionHashSet2,samples);
             
             testRetain3Quarter(collectionHashSet2,collectionHashSetDestination);
             
        }
        
        public static void voidTestRemoveFromArrayList(){
             Collection<Vector3d> collectionArrayList=new ArrayList<Vector3d>();
             preamble(collectionArrayList,1000);
             testRemoveQuarter(collectionArrayList);
        }
        
        
        public static void preamble(Collection<Vector3d> collection, int numberToAdd){
            //not part of timed test
            for(int i=0;i<numberToAdd;i++){
                collection.add(new Vector3d(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random()));
            }
        }
        
        public static void testRemoveQuarter(Collection<Vector3d> collection){
            Iterator<Vector3d> iterator=collection.iterator();
            
            int counter=0;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                counter++;
                iterator.next();
                if ((counter%4)==0){
                    counter=0;
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
        
        public static void testRetain3QuarterPresized(Collection<Vector3d> collection, Collection<Vector3d> destinationCollection){
            testRetain3Quarter(collection, destinationCollection);
        }
        public static void testRetain3Quarter(Collection<Vector3d> collection, Collection<Vector3d> destinationCollection){
            Iterator<Vector3d> iterator=collection.iterator();
            
            int counter=0;
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                counter++;
                Vector3d processing=iterator.next();
                if ((counter%4)!=0){
                    counter=0;
                    destinationCollection.add(processing);
                }
            }
        }
        
}
```

N.B. it is important to note that as far as the collection is concerned it contains references to objects, as such my choice of a particular class of object is irrelevant

Comment: Regarding the results of the ArrayList the conclusion is: you do nothing wrong choosing the approach of creating a new ArrayList.  

Did you initialized the new ArrayList with a certain capacity to prevent it from resizing several times?

Comment: @LuCio no, presizing the destination array list would probably increase speed further

Comment: @LuCio Added presized results

Answer (score 0):

You should benchmark different java.util.List implementations, focus on addig and removing elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to the `ArrayList` I'd say the second option is way faster. But you should really benchmark it yourself and also try the `LinkedList` variant. As the Java `LinkedList` is a double linked list as far as I know, adding elements at the end tends to be faster than with an `ArrayList`. Especially if you don't know the initial size.

Comment: Adding items to the end of an ArrayList is also very fast since the list only needs to get copied when it exceeds its initial capacity. The difference is that REMOVING items from the middle of a LinkedList is O(1) if you already have an iterator at the point of removal while list.removs(x) runs in O(n) for ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some benchmark like this:

```
List<Object> arrayRemove = new ArrayList<Object>(initialMax);
List<Object> arrayCopy = new ArrayList<Object>((int) (initialMax * (1+retain)/2));
List<Object> linkedRemove = new LinkedList<Object>();
List<Object> linkedCopy = new LinkedList<Object>();

for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
    arrayRemove.add(new Object());
    linkedRemove.add(new Object());
}

Random rnd = new Random();
//Begin benchmarking
for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
    if (rnd.nextDouble() < retain) {
        linkedCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //1.
        // arrayCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //2. (same code but...)
    } else {
        // linkedRemove.remove(0); //3.
        // arrayRemove.remove(0); //4.
    }
}
// End benchmarking
```

where `initialMax = 1500; retain = 2/3` and you test all four methods separately.
Also, when your "Figures" can be in random order, consider using a `HashSet`.

---

### EDIT

(Basic) tests have shown that Method 4 is useless and the others are about the same speed:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;


public class Test {
private static final int initialMax = 150000;
private static final double retain = 2/3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Object> arrayRemove = new ArrayList<Object>(initialMax);
    List<Object> arrayCopy = new ArrayList<Object>((int) (initialMax * (1+retain)/2));
    List<Object> linkedRemove = new LinkedList<Object>();
    List<Object> linkedCopy = new LinkedList<Object>();

    for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
        arrayRemove.add(new Object());
        linkedRemove.add(new Object());
    }

    Random rnd = new Random();
    //Begin benchmarking
    Date[] ds = new Date[5];
    ds[0] = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < retain) {
            linkedCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //1.
            // arrayCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //2. (same code but...)
        } else {
            // linkedRemove.remove(i); //3.
            // arrayRemove.remove(i); //4.
        }
    }
    ds[1] = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < retain) {
            // linkedCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //1.
            arrayCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //2. (same code but...)
        } else {
            // linkedRemove.remove(i); //3.
            // arrayRemove.remove(i); //4.
        }
    }
    ds[2] = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < retain) {
            // linkedCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //1.
            // arrayCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //2. (same code but...)
        } else {
            linkedRemove.remove(0); //3.
            // arrayRemove.remove(0); //4.
        }
    }
    ds[3] = new Date();
    for (int i = 0; i < initialMax; i++) {
        if (rnd.nextDouble() < retain) {
            // linkedCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //1.
            // arrayCopy.add(arrayRemove.get(i)); //2. (same code but...)
        } else {
            // linkedRemove.remove(0); //3.
            arrayRemove.remove(0); //4.
        }
    }
    ds[4] = new Date();
    // End benchmarking
    long[] diff = new long[4];
    System.out.println("Results:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        diff[i] = (ds[i + 1].getTime() - ds[i].getTime());
        System.out.println((i+1) + ".: " + diff[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Results are

> Results:
>   1.: 0-15
>   2.: 0
>   3.: 0-15
>   4.: 6895